# How to apply media query CSS rules to iframe content

Tags: css, iframe, media

I've got this set of code I would like to apply to my iframe, but it doesn't work.

```
@media only screen
and (min-width : 320px)
and (max-width : 480px) {
#postframe article{display:none;}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you serve the frame's document with that CSS in the first place?

Answer (score 9):

Solved… My iframe width was 960px, so until you don't change width to 320px it could not recognize the media query!!

Thanks all

Comment: Accept your answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript... maybe like this:

```
var cssLink = document.createElement("link");
cssLink.href = "yourStyle.css";  
cssLink.rel = "stylesheet";  
cssLink.type = "text/css";  
frames['yourFrame'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);
```

Comment: Ok! For example the last line you wrote should be something like this: frames['#postframe'].document.body.article(display:none); ? And where should i insert media queries?

Comment: I've got a wordpress theme where posts are loaded inside an iframe.
The single loop page of projects is named "single.php"… I can't define @media only screen
and (min-width : 320px)
and (max-width : 480px) {
#postframe article{display:none;}
} also if I try to write it inside head tag of single.php!

Why this?